# Create Audio by Special Frequency under 20ms

Tags: ios

I want to create a sound by selected frequency. My code works right above 23 ms, but not under 23 ms. Because my RenderTone method (i found on internet this is not my code) is called in each 23 ms. How can i decrease the time of iteration? The quality of sound can be changed (not too much)
Thank you

```
OSStatus RenderTone(
                void *inRefCon,
                AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags,
                const AudioTimeStamp        *inTimeStamp,
                UInt32                      inBusNumber,
                UInt32                      inNumberFrames,
                AudioBufferList             *ioData){
ViewController *viewController =
(__bridge ViewController *)inRefCon;
double theta = viewController->theta;
double theta_increment = 2.0 * M_PI * viewController->frequency / viewController->sampleRate;

// This is a mono tone generator so we only need the first buffer
const int channel = 0;
Float32 *buffer = (Float32 *)ioData->mBuffers[channel].mData;

// Generate the samples
NSLog(@"entered the method");
for (UInt32 frame = 0; frame < inNumberFrames; frame++)
{

    buffer[frame] = sin(theta) * viewController->amp1;

    theta += theta_increment;
    if (theta > 2.0 * M_PI)
    {
        theta -= 2.0 * M_PI;
    }
}

viewController->theta = theta;

return noErr;}


void ToneInterruptionListener(void *inClientData, UInt32 inInterruptionState){
ViewController *viewController =
(__bridge ViewController *)inClientData;

[viewController stop];}

- (void)createToneUnit{
// Configure the search parameters to find the default playback output unit
// (called the kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO on iOS but
// kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput on Mac OS X)
AudioComponentDescription defaultOutputDescription;
defaultOutputDescription.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
defaultOutputDescription.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
defaultOutputDescription.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
defaultOutputDescription.componentFlags = 0;
defaultOutputDescription.componentFlagsMask = 0;

// Get the default playback output unit
AudioComponent defaultOutput = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &defaultOutputDescription);
NSAssert(defaultOutput, @"Can't find default output");

// Create a new unit based on this that we'll use for output
OSErr err = AudioComponentInstanceNew(defaultOutput, &toneUnit);
NSAssert1(toneUnit, @"Error creating unit: %hd", err);

// Set our tone rendering function on the unit
AURenderCallbackStruct input;
input.inputProc = RenderTone;
input.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)(self);
err = AudioUnitSetProperty(toneUnit,
                           kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                           kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                           0,
                           &input,
                           sizeof(input));
NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error setting callback: %hd", err);

// Set the format to 32 bit, single channel, floating point, linear PCM
const int four_bytes_per_float = 4;
const int eight_bits_per_byte = 8;
AudioStreamBasicDescription streamFormat;
streamFormat.mSampleRate = sampleRate;
streamFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
streamFormat.mFormatFlags =
kAudioFormatFlagsNativeFloatPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved;
streamFormat.mBytesPerPacket = four_bytes_per_float;
streamFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
streamFormat.mBytesPerFrame = four_bytes_per_float;
streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
streamFormat.mBitsPerChannel = four_bytes_per_float * eight_bits_per_byte;
err = AudioUnitSetProperty (toneUnit,
                            kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                            kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                            0,
                            &streamFormat,
                            sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription));
NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error setting stream format: %hd", err);}
```

There is the code for playing sound by frequency

```
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];


UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None;

AudioSessionSetProperty (
                         kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,
                         sizeof (audioRouteOverride),
                         &audioRouteOverride
                         );

        [self createToneUnit];
    amp1=0.25;
    // Stop changing parameters on the unit
    OSErr err = AudioUnitInitialize(toneUnit);
    NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error initializing unit: %ld", err);

    // Start playback
    err = AudioOutputUnitStart(toneUnit);
    NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error starting unit: %ld", err);
```

There is Log here: (23 ms)

```
2015-05-21 10:26:39.145 CreateBinarySound[223:7676] entered the method
2015-05-21 10:26:39.168 CreateBinarySound[223:7676] entered the method
```